# How to remove react native navigation by wix

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm working on a React Native project that use [wix/react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) for the navigation and i hate it. I would like to remove this library but reading the [documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/installing) i found that the installation of wix RNN require changes to the android and ios folders and you must also run some command that make automatic changes to the project. Is there a way to entire remove the library and return to the initial situation?

Comment: any solution so far? I have the same problem here

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the manual installation steps in reverse order, it  worked for me. Revert these files `android/build.gradle`, `MainActivity.java`, `MainApplication.java` and `index.js`. Also run `npx pod-install` and remove all imports of react-native-navigation and all community libraries related to rnn from your code.